# Enabling combobox based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have this radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="pie" value="pie" />
<input type="radio" name="type" id="bar" value="bar" /><
<input type="radio" name="type" id="line" value="line" />
```

And I want a combobox based on seletected radio button.

```
<select id="Xcombo1" class="Xcombo">
<option value = "" >This options should be based on seletec radio</option>
</select>
```

Some code that ive already have:

```
$('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val(); // to get selected radio.
```

My question is, how can I have those options based on selected radio button ?

note: Anytime I selected a diferent radio button those options should dynamically change 
Cheers.

Comment: So are you saying for example if I click on a radio with value pie you would like the select dropdown to add a new option with the same value of pie?

Comment: ahaha @StevenFarley, the options content arent important at the moment. Could be anything.

Comment: if it dynamically change that means you have to have a set of values related to each radio option which can be added into the select options

Comment: I just read your note, it sounds like you want the dropdown to show a different set of options for each radio selection. Is that what your asking?

Comment: @Swarnajith, yes its that :P

Comment: A simple show and hide would work best in this case IMO.

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. You can fake them with JavaScript, but you just have a select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example for you to test, hopefully I understood what you wanted

**HTML:**

```
<label for="pie">PIE</label><input type="radio" name="type" id="pie" value="pie" />
<br />
<label for="bar">BAR</label><input type="radio" name="type" id="bar" value="bar" />
<br />
<label for="line">LINE</label><input type="radio" name="type" id="line" value="line" />
<br />
<br />

<select id="combopie" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="pie">Pie Options Here</option>
</select>

<select id="combobar" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="bar">Bar Options Here</option>
</select>

<select id="comboline" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="line">Line Options Here</option>
</select>
```

**​jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=\'radio\']').click(function () {
        $('select.Xcombo').hide();
        $('#combo' + $(this).attr('id')).show();                
    });
});​
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2rdG/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input").click(function(){
 if($(this).attr("checked"))
{
    if(this.id == "pie")
    {
        $("#Xcombo1").html("<option value='1' >1</option><option value='2' >2</option>");
    }
    else if( this.id == "bar")
    {

        $("#Xcombo1").html("<option value='3' >3</option><option value='4' >4</option>");
    }
    else
    {

        $("#Xcombo1").html("<option value='5' >5</option><option value='6' >6</option>");
    }
}
});
```

Check the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/quG2S/12/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="pie" value="pie" />
<input type="radio" name="type" id="bar" value="bar" />
<input type="radio" name="type" id="line" value="line" />

<select id="Xcombo1" class="Xcombo">
   <option value = "pie">Pie</option>
   <option value = "bar">Bar</option>
   <option value = "line">Line</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    $("#Xcombo1 option[value='" + $(this).val() +"']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

This function binds a function to the click event of each radio button that uses the value of the clicked radio to select the appropriate option and set its selected property.

Normal Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g82dB/

If you want to **dynamically** append the elements the following script can be used.  It checks to make sure the option does not already exist, then either appends or selects.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    if($("#Xcombo1 option[value='" + $(this).val() +"']").length ==0){
        var option = $("<option />",{
            "value": $(this).val(),
            "text": $(this).val(),
            "selected": "selected"
        });
        $("#Xcombo1").append(option);
    }else{
        $("#Xcombo1 option[value='" + $(this).val() +"']").prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

This works with the following HTML:

Dynamic Element Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g82dB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example :

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=type]').change(function() {
        var radio = $(this);
        // The "change" event can be triggered for an "unselecting" radio button, so we must check it.
        if (radio.is(':checked')) {
            // You may want to do something else
            $('#Xcombo1 option').attr('value', radio.val());
        }            
    });        
});
```

And a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wNZHr/

If you want to display different options according to the selected radio button, you can create options in javascript, or you can create all options directly in your html and use show/hide to only display the options you want.

Comment: Yes It may be better if I create options in javascript